# How to create this template in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: template

I have a sharepoint portal in sharepoint 2010. This web application is using the publishing template. Now I would like to create a new template with some webparts like :

calendar
announcements
shared documents
tasks
links

When I click on site settings, new site, I can select templates. I would like that my custom template will also available in this list. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom site definition, following this great guide provided by Microsoft,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#stepbystep

OR

You can create a custom web template and add all of webparts you want and there configuration too. Here's the link you need to go through,

[How to: Create a Custom Web Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff408263%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Another way I know is to customize your publishing web and then add this at end of your URL to get web template,

```
URL /_layouts/SaveTmpl.aspx
```